# Insertion sort php

Tags: php, sorting

Have someone an idea why the programm doesn't enter in the function?
This is a simple insertion sort algorithm.

```
<?php
    function insert($my_array)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<count($my_array);$i++){
            $val = $my_array[$i];
            $j = $i-1;
            while($j>=0 && $my_array[$j] > $val){
                $my_array[$j+1] = $my_array[$j];
                $j--;
            }
            $my_array[$j+1] = $val;
        }
    return $my_array;
    $test_array = array(3, 0, 2, 5, -1, 4, 1);
    echo "Original Array :\n";
    echo implode(', ',$test_array );
    echo "\nSorted Array :\n";
    print_r(insert($test_array));
    ?>
```

Comment: you missed a `}` after `return $my_array;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

} is missing try now

```
   function insert($my_array)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<count($my_array);$i++){
            $val = $my_array[$i];
            $j = $i-1;
            while($j>=0 && $my_array[$j] > $val){
                $my_array[$j+1] = $my_array[$j];
                $j--;
            }
            $my_array[$j+1] = $val;
        }
    return $my_array;
}
    $test_array = array(3, 0, 2, 5, -1, 4, 1);
    echo "Original Array :\n";
    echo implode(', ',$test_array );
    echo "\nSorted Array :\n";
    print_r(insert($test_array));
```

**OutPut** : Original Array : 3, 0, 2, 5, -1, 4, 1 Sorted Array : `Array ( [0] => -1 [1] => 0 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [4] => 3 [5] => 4 [6] => 5 )`

Answer (score 0):

```
$data_set = [3,44,38,5,15,26,27,2,46,4];

function insertion_sort($data_set){
    $number_of_items = count($data_set);
    for($i = 0; $i <= $number_of_items - 2; $i++){
        $k = $i;
        for($j = $i + 1; $j > 0; $j--){
            if($data_set[$j] < $data_set[$k]){
                $temp = $data_set[$j];
                $data_set[$j] = $data_set[$k];
                $data_set[$k] = $temp;
            }
            if($k > 0 )
                $k--;
        }
    }
    return $data_set;
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r(insertion_sort($data_set));
echo '</pre>';
```